# Does Rydberg constant vary with mass?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mass, atomic-physics, physical-constants

Does [Rydberg constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_constant) vary with mass? I researched a bit and some sources say it doesn't depend on mass of the element. How is this possible? Doesn't the name itself say its a constant?

Comment: You can see the mass(es) in the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_constant#Rydberg_constant). The masses of electrons and protons are constants.

Comment: Welcome Maths lover to Physics Stack Exchange. It is best to give links to the "some sources" so people don't have to guess what they are saying. Also, I assume "doe'sk" is a typo for "does"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Rydberg constant depends on the mass. This dependence can be seen from the perspective of Bohr's atomic theory for example. However, the Rydberg constant was established prior to any modern, including Borh's, atomic theories. The Balmer lines of the hydrogen spectra could be related using the Rydberg constant. There was certainly no reason then to doubt that it had any variation as there was no common knowledge of isotopic hydrogen. Providing that you are treating a specific isotope of hydrogen, then the Rydberg constant is truly constant.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_constant opens with:

*"In spectroscopy, the Rydberg constant, symbol
$ R_{\infty }$ for heavy atoms or
$R_{\text{H}}$ for hydrogen."*

and follows with:

$$ R_{\text{H}} = \frac{m_p}{m_p+m_e}R_{\infty}$$

If this is still unclear, it's because the one electron atom is a two-body problem in the coordinates of the nucleus and the electron $\vec r_N, \vec r_e$: six degrees of spatial freedom:

$$ H(\vec r_N, \vec r_e) = \frac{\hat{p}_N^2}{2m_N} + \frac{\hat{p}_e^2}{2m_e} + V(|\vec r_N-\vec r_e|)$$

We don't want to solve all that, so we separate it into:

$$ H_{CoM}(\vec R) = \frac{\hat P^2}{2M} $$
$$ H(\vec r) = \frac{\hat p^2}{2m} + V(\vec r) $$

with the center-of-mass coordinate:

$$ \vec R = \frac{m_N\vec r_N + m_e\vec r_e}{m_N + m_e}$$

which as a simple free particle solution, and:

$$ \vec r = \vec r_e - \vec r_N $$

and the reduced mass:

$$ m = \frac{m_Nm_e}{m_N+m_e} $$

so there is clearly a mass dependence to the ionization energy.

The physical reason for this that the nucleus is not stationary. When the electron is in a state with quantum numbers $(n, l, m)$..which is Laguerre polynomial based radial function in $n$, times a spherical harmonic $Y_l^m$, the nucleus is also in that state, but we regularly forget that when looking at pictures of orbits.

You can estimate the size of the nucleus's orbital as $\frac{m_e}{m_N}a_0\approx 32\,{\rm fm}$, which is about 40 times bigger than a proton.